# dependency injection best practice

Tags: php, unit-testing, dependency-injection, service-locator

I'm getting into unit testing, and searching for days to find an answer, I found none.
I'm writing an app which reads the file system, searching for images and videos.
Then I want to instantiate a model for each image.

```
class A 
{
   private function readFS ($path)
   {
       ... read file system, collect the media into an array ...
       foreach($files as $currentFile) {
            $return[$file->type][] = $file;
       }
       return $return;
   }

   // type can either be Image or Video
   private function instantiateModels ($type, $file)
   {
    return new $type(['file' => $file]);
   }

   public function processFolder ($path)
   {
    $files = $this->readFS($path);

    foreach($files as $type => $files) {
        foreach($files as $currentFile) {
            $type[] = $this->instantiateModels($type, $currentFile);
        }
    }

    ... then every media instance is saved to the database by calling it's save method: e.g.: Image::save() ...
}
```

then various data will be retrieved from the Image | Video instance and will be stored in a database.

Now, what is the best practice to do?
Do I use Dependency Injection, or simply instantiate the models as it written in the example above?
Then how do I unit test this class? If I understand right, because of blackbox testing and encapsulating, I should mock the instantiateModels() method, but private method shouldn't be tested or mocked.

If I dependency inject a factory, which can instantiate either an Image model or a Video model:

```
class A 
{
      public function __construct (Factory $mediaFactory)
      {
             $this->factory = $mediaFactory;
      }

      private function instantiateModels ($type, $file)
      {
            return $this->factory->build($type, $file);
      }

      ...
}
```

then I can mock the factory, but as far as I understand it, that will be  a service locator, which is an anti pattern.

What do I do in this situation?

EDIT:
Or maybe the problem is, that my class A wants to do too many things at once, hence not meeting the 'single responsibility' principle?
May I create a class B which will search for media files and a class C that is a factory, which can instantiate Image and Video instances, and class A should take class B and class C as dependencies?
But then again, how do I unit test the factory class?

Comment: Why not pass the A object into the factory and the factory creates the new media instance? The factory should get all it needs to create a new model from A exposed public apis.

Comment: @frz3993 you say, that I should pass an instance of A to the factory?

Comment: Just a suggestion. The factory having a method like `function createMediaFromA(A){}`. So, you can test the factory with mocked A, and delegate the responsibility of object creation to the factory. And A will be relieved from the responsibility of creating the object.

Comment: Therefore, A will not be depending on the factory anymore.